# Set height for a relative layout containing a listView

Tags: android, listview, layout, android-relativelayout

I'm currently developing an Android app and I've got an issue concerning layout. In my XML layout file, I create a relative layout (fill_parent for width and wrap_content for height) which contains a list View (or possibly an expendable List View - fill_parent for height and width). In the corresponding activity onCreate method, I just set the adapter corresponding to my list and attach it to my list. The problem is that when I run my app the relative layout only has a size of 93dip and so it hides my list which has a size from 67 to 210dip when I would like the relative layout height to stick to the list current size (The size will never change through action in the activity just possibly when creating or resuming the activity). Would anyone have an idea of a solution to fix that ?

Some code as asked :

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/content" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:background="@drawable/row" 
              android:layout_below="@+id/header" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <ListView android:id="@+id/list" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:background="@drawable/listrow"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And in the java file (where snapRecords is my object lists):

```
m_panel = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.lastFareRecordPanel);
ListView lv = (ListView)m_panel.findViewById(R.id.list);
final QuickSnapBookmarksAdapter adapter = new QuickSnapBookmarksAdapter(snapRecords, getApplicationContext(), this, lv);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Many thanks in advance for your help !

Benja

Comment: Can you add the layout and some code please?

Comment: why don't you use LinearLayout? is there any specific reason to use RelativeLayout in your project?

Comment: Well, in theory I could modify it but I would prefer not to since that would imply a lot of changes for me but also for the other people working on the project... If I really have to I will but I first wanted to know if a solution might exist to my problem with a Relative Layout...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similiar situation.When I changed parent layout into LinearLayout, it is working.Here is the code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/prev"
            android:layout_width="106dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="prev"
            android:paddingTop="8dip"
            android:src="@drawable/previous" >
        </ImageButton>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="106dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="next"
            android:paddingTop="8dip"
            android:src="@drawable/next" >
        </ImageButton>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Logout"
            android:layout_width="106dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="logout"
            android:paddingTop="8dip"
            android:src="@drawable/logout1"
            android:text="@string/Logout" >
        </ImageButton>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="330dip" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="338dip"
        android:text="@string/EmptyList"
        android:textSize="35dip" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/prev1"
            android:layout_width="106dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="prev"
            android:src="@drawable/previous" >
        </ImageButton>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/next1"
            android:layout_width="106dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="next"
            android:src="@drawable/next" >
        </ImageButton>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/Logout"
            android:layout_width="106dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@null"
            android:onClick="logout"
            android:src="@drawable/logout1"
            android:text="@string/Logout" >
        </ImageButton>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, I was testing your solution while adding some code to my question... But not... that doesn't work in my case... Exactly same problem...

Comment: Is there is any other views other than list view? Try to remove the parent layout,If listview is the only child...

Comment: why is this answer accepted if it didn't fix the problem? Do you still need an answer on this or not?